# Spring 4 undetermined amount of datasources

Tags: java, database, spring, spring-mvc, datasource

I try to make some spring project with n datasources. I know, it's possible to create several data sources but I need to create one datasource per .properties file. For example, I have 5 .properties with info about DB, and then I should create somehow 5 datasourcers.

Maybe I have a bad approach, I looking for some mechanism that will allow user choose DB, info about DB's I have in .properties files and amount of datasourcers depends on this .properties. I have to find solution to dynamically create  datasourcers or implement some datasource pool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dynamically create a new Spring context with just this chosen DataSource bean.

Or you can create a list of DataSources at startup. Or even a map with every DS mapped to a name. In Spring Java config file in a @Bean method you just read a directory with property files and for each file create a data source, put it into a map under its name. Return this map from the @Bean method and that map becomes a Spring bean which you can inject anywhere and use any of the DataSources from the map.